# AttributeError: module 'torch._six' has no attribute 'PY37'

Tags: pytorch

I have the newest torch installed, and my CUDA version is 11.7, so I chose the closest one torch1.12.1+cu116. However, it does not have PY3 or PY37... Can anyone help me with that? The code that I need to use has PY37 and I don't know how to make the code run...

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.12.1+cu116'
>>> torch._six.PY3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'torch._six' has no attribute 'PY3'
>>> torch._six.PY37
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'torch._six' has no attribute 'PY37'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've downgraded torch to 1.4 version and python to 3.7 version. Not sure if it is an optimal configuration, but somehow it worked.